# app engine java.security.AccessControlException

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine

when i  use app engine to develop my apps,and i just want to read the file stored in the gaevfs using the code : this.shpAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(this.shpFileName, "r"); but it throw new AccessControlException("access denied "+perm, perm);so can someone tell me how to solve the problem?

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission gae:\F:\workspace\GeoCloud\war\gaevfs\cecc8aa0-7405-102e-b976-026d7f000001\longrive.shp read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:166)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:203)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:98)
    at com.vobject.appengine.java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:90)
```

Comment: What is your code doing to cause this? It looks like you might be trying to write to a file -- App Engine apps don't have write access to the filesystem, just the datastore and blobstore. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox

Comment: i just want to read the file stored in the gaevfs using the code :   this.shpAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(this.shpFileName, "r"); but it  throw new AccessControlException("access denied "+perm, perm);so can you tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Are you following this [guideline](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html#readfile)?

Comment: i think i am following the guideline. the file i need read from is stored in the GAEVFS,so it isn't in the following locations: war/WEB-INF.the path of the file stored in the GAEVFS is gae:///F:/workspace/GeoCloud/war/**** .the method i am using to read from the file is the RandomAccessFile.